# How do I get rid of the space between the menu bar and the side nav?

Tags: html, css

How do I get rid of the space between the menu bar and the sidebar caused by typing hello.

I have tried
*display:inline-block;* and *overflow:hidden;* which got rid of the white space that was there previously and now filled it up with a color. I have also tried taking the content div and moving it so it isn't a parent(?) of .sidebar but then "hello" just ends up on the bottom of the page. I want to keep the "hello" text centered on the yellow area without having a space between the side bar and the menu bar.

[Picture of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn53s.jpg)

```css
.menucontain{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap:5px;
    color:#F2F0D0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#204959;
    font-family:helvetica;
    padding:15px;
  }
    .sidebar{
      background:#204959;
    width:18%;
    height:800px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#F2F0D0;
    font-family:helvetica;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6 ,50px);
    grid-gap:2px;
     }
    .side1{
    background:gray;
    padding-top:15px;
      }
   
  .content{
    background-color:#F2F0D0;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
      }
```

```html
<div class="menucontain">

  <div class="menu1">Menu1</div>
<div class="menu2">Menu2</div>
 <div class="menu3">Menu3</div>
 <div class="menu4">Menu4</div>
 <div class="menu5">Menu5</div>
<div class="menu6">Menu6</div>
  <!--menu contain div on next line-->
</div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <p>hello</p>

<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="side1">About</div>
  <div class="side1">Blog</div>
  <div class="side1">Sales</div>
  <div class="side1">Partners</div>
  <div class="side1">Portfolio</div>
  <div class="side1">Contact</div>
  </div>   
  </div>
```

Comment: its because you added that between the navbar and the sidebar. As such it follows the actual flow. You have to move the sidebar outside of the normal flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct solution to your problem.

First, move the tag `<p>` in sequence for **sidebar**. Like this:

```
...
<div class="sidebar">
        <div class="side1">About</div>
        <div class="side1">Blog</div>
        <div class="side1">Sales</div>
        <div class="side1">Partners</div>
        <div class="side1">Portfolio</div>
        <div class="side1">Contact</div>
    </div>

    <p>hello</p>
...
```

Secondly, assign the **grid** rules for the `.content` class by adding this to your css:

```
.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 18% 1fr;
}
```

And remove the width rules - `width: 18%` out of `.sidebar` selector. Because we defined the width as **18%** in the *grid* rule above.

```css
.menucontain {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 5px;
    color: #f2f0d0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #204959;
    font-family: helvetica;
    padding: 15px;
}

.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 18% 1fr;
}

.sidebar {
    background: #204959;
    /*width: 18%;*/
    height: 800px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f2f0d0;
    font-family: helvetica;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 50px);
    grid-gap: 2px;
}

.side1 {
    background: gray;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.content {
    background-color: #f2f0d0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="menucontain">
    <div class="menu1">Menu1</div>
    <div class="menu2">Menu2</div>
    <div class="menu3">Menu3</div>
    <div class="menu4">Menu4</div>
    <div class="menu5">Menu5</div>
    <div class="menu6">Menu6</div>
    <!--menu contain div on next line-->
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="side1">About</div>
        <div class="side1">Blog</div>
        <div class="side1">Sales</div>
        <div class="side1">Partners</div>
        <div class="side1">Portfolio</div>
        <div class="side1">Contact</div>
    </div>

    <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @lulz96, no problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

The p tag is a block element, to remove the space you have to remove

hello <\p> from the 'content' class

Use flex display or grid display on the 'content' class

Comment: This works somewhat, but I want to be able to write on the yellow area which is colored using .content.

Answer (score 0):

Re-aling the 3 different parts (menucontain, sidebar, content) into a grid by declaring the body as a grid. Sicne you already use grids to style the menucontain and sidebar, you have to switch them to a subgrid.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 18vw auto;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.menucontain {
  grid-column: span 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  color: #F2F0D0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #204959;
  font-family: helvetica;
  padding: 15px;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #204959;
  height: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F2F0D0;
  font-family: helvetica;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 50px);
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.side1 {
  background: gray;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #F2F0D0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="menucontain">
  <div class="menu1">Menu1</div>
  <div class="menu2">Menu2</div>
  <div class="menu3">Menu3</div>
  <div class="menu4">Menu4</div>
  <div class="menu5">Menu5</div>
  <div class="menu6">Menu6</div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="side1">About</div>
  <div class="side1">Blog</div>
  <div class="side1">Sales</div>
  <div class="side1">Partners</div>
  <div class="side1">Portfolio</div>
  <div class="side1">Contact</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```